# Xcode 8 Simulator crash if changing device type

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, ios-simulator

I am working around with  Xcode 8. But I have one problem, specifically when I try to change the device type in simulator, it crashes and I get a crash message

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
'*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b5934b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001035ba21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103a8af1b -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 203
    3   Mahroosa                            0x0000000102e207c7 -[MainViewController viewSliderControllerAtIndex:] + 151
    4   Mahroosa                            0x0000000102e21117 -[MainViewController LoadSlides] + 1495
    5   Mahroosa                            0x0000000102e25b32 -[MainViewController TimerTick:] + 98
    6   Foundation                          0x0000000103115144 __NSFireTimer + 83
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103aeb964 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103aeb5f3 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103aeb17a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 250
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ae2f01 __CFRunLoopRun + 2065
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ae2494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108f2ca6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001048ebf34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    14  Mahroosa                            0x0000000102e34a2f main + 111
    15  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010628868d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any ideas?.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to add it as libc++abi.tbd by removing the old one.

Comment: As it says, you've tried to access an object beyond the bounds of an array. Can you see the stack trace showing where this happened in your code?

Comment: @jtbandes Thanks for the reply..How can i  solve this problem.?

Comment: In `LoadSlides` you are calling `viewSliderControllerAtIndex` with a bad index. The array is empty.